# Azure B2C custom attribute fixed length

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

Does anyone know how to add a fixed length validation for a custom attribute to Azure B2C signup/sign in the template?

I'm trying to figure how to restrict user to enter just 10 digits.

For example, user attribute (Telephone Number) = Restrict to integer and only 10 digits.

Any comments or advice is truly appreciated.

Comment: Please use IsLengthRange and MatchesRegex to validate the custom attribute. Refer document https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/predicates

Comment: @Jit_MSFT : Thanks you Jit_MSFT. Document you provided is very useful, but works only for Custom Policy and not for User Flow provided by Azure Signin/Signup. I believe we have to use jquery script instead of html code.

Comment: Thanks and here is the document. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/javascript-and-page-layout?pivots=b2c-user-flow